# VS returns this when I try to run python /bin/sh: python: command not found (macOS Ventura 13.0.01)

Tags: python, macos

I have installed python as an add-on on VS code. I have also downloaded python from browser so I should have it. Read that it could be because of code runner or wrong path.

The OS I'm running is Ventura 13.0.01

If I press the downward arrow right of the run button in VS it returns my code under the Terminal tab. I've only used JS before this so I really don't know how Python code should run.
I have tried earlier answers that have pointed towards the path direction of Python but didn't understand so much.

Answer (score 0):

if you can check version of python in terminal

```
python -V
```

then an can run your code in this way

```
python /path/to/python_file.py
```

your question title looks like python was not installed yet or removed.

I'm using Catalina and Big Sur and there is no problems because python is installed from the box.

[Python3 now included with Ventura](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/254320722) read comments

Comment: Where am I supposed to write this?